# Indy TCP - Sending and receiving stream

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy10

Here's how the receiver will receive the stream.

```
 Ms := TMemoryStream.Create;

    try
      Ms.Position := 0;
      Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(Ms, -1,false);
    finally
      Ms.Free;
    end;
```

If the receiver wants to cancel it

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try Ms.Free; except end; 
end;
```

This doesn't work well, the application sometimes closes.

Also for the sender...

```
    Ms := TMemoryStream.Create;

    try
      Ms.Position := 0;
      Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      Connection.IOHandler.Write(Ms, 0, True);
    finally
      Ms.Free;
    end;
```

The same with the sender in canceling the stream.

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try Ms.Free; except end; 
end;
```

What is the proper way to cancel the stream that is being send or receive ?

Comment: No, that won't work well, pulling the rug from under Indy's feet.

Answer (score 1):

Forcing a memory access error is a **horrible** way to abort a send/receive operation.  There are three other ways I can think of to abort it:

1. Raise an exception in the context of Indy's own send/receive logic.  Either raise an exception in Indy's `OnWork` event, or derive a new `TStream` class that raises an exception in its `Write()` and `Read()` implementations.
2. Break up the data into smaller chunks, each with its own send/receive call, then check for your termination condition in between each chunk.
3. Close the socket.